# Use the same function on different elements in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a group of selects (birth_year, birth_month and birth_day). I wrote this code which fills a drop-down with correct number of days of a month, disables the month, day drop-down if no year is selected etc. My problem is that I have another group of drop-downs (entry_year, entry_month, entry_day) on the form which i want to use this function with, and I have no idea how could I do that.

How can I modify this function to work with another set of select boxes?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sl_birth_year').change(function() {
    var birth_year = $('#sl_birth_year').val();
    if (birth_year != 0)
  $('#sl_birth_month').attr('disabled', false);
    else {
  $('#sl_birth_month').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#sl_birth_day').attr('disabled', true);
}
$('#sl_birth_month').val(0);
$('#sl_birth_day').val(0);
  }),
  $('#sl_birth_month').change(function() {
    var birth_year = $('#sl_birth_year').val();
    var birth_month = $('#sl_birth_month').val();
    if (birth_month != 0) {
  $('#sl_birth_day').attr('disabled', false);
  var post_url = "/index.php/admin/get_days/" + birth_year + "/" + birth_month;
  $.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: post_url,
    success: function(num_of_days) {
      $('#sl_birth_day').empty();
      $('#sl_birth_day').append('<option value="0"> </option>');
      for (var i = 0; i < num_of_days; i++) {
        var string = '<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + (i + 1) + "</option>";
    $('#sl_birth_day').append('<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + (i + 1) + "</option>");
      }
    }
  });
}
    else {
  $('#sl_birth_day').val(0);
  $('#sl_birth_day').attr('disabled', true);
}
  });
});
```

Comment: Correct tabulation would help read the code. Meanwhile -- you can create this as a named function, which receives parameters for object ID (year, month, day). Then call this function on birth ids, and entry ids.

Answer (score 0):

you variablize the ids on the elements and pass these into a function. If I were I would break this code down into a series of smaller functions. Find common functionality and put that into a function and then reuse it e.g. you could create small function that you can pass in an array elements to disable them.

Comment: -1 for trying to invent the word "variablize." (Not really, but it still looks awful.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a new function in your javascript which accepts parameter which you can pass in for the different drop down groups you have. It can be simplified and/or made more efficient but this is for your specific code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    SomeFunction('.sl_birth_year', '#sl_birth_month', '#sl_birth_day');
});

function SomeFunction(strYearClass, strYearID, strMonth, strDay) {
    $(strYearClass).change(function() { 
    var birth_year = $(strYearID).val(); 
    if (birth_year != 0) 
  $(strMonth).attr('disabled', false); 
    else { 
  $(strMonth).attr('disabled', true); 
  $(strDay).attr('disabled', true); 
} 
$(strMonth).val(0); 
$(strDay).val(0); 
  }), 
  $(strMonth).change(function() { 
    var birth_year = $(strYear).val(); 
    var birth_month = $(strMonth).val(); 
    if (birth_month != 0) { 
  $(strDay).attr('disabled', false); 
  var post_url = "/index.php/admin/get_days/" + birth_year + "/" + birth_month; 
  $.ajax ({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: post_url, 
    success: function(num_of_days) { 
      $(strDay).empty(); 
      $(strDay).append('<option value="0"> </option>'); 
      for (var i = 0; i < num_of_days; i++) { 
        var string = '<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + (i + 1) + "</option>"; 
    $(strDay).append('<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + (i + 1) + "</option>"); 
      } 
    } 
  }); 
} 
    else { 
  $(strDay).val(0); 
  $(strDay).attr('disabled', true); 
} 
  }); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class names for the elements, pass a reference to a wrapping element to the function and determine the elements **relative** to the parent wrapper.

Something like this:

```
function setDrops(parent) {
 $('.sl_birth_year').change(function() {
   var yearTarget = $(parent).find('.sl_birth_yearVAL')
   var birth_year = $(yearTarget).val();

.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each set of select boxes in its own div with a class like "date_container", give each select type its own class name (e.g. "year", "month" and "day"), then change your function so it recieves one of your wrapping div and work relatively to it.

I won't write it for you but it could look like :

Your html:

```
<div id="this_one_date_container" class="date_container">
  <select class="year" ...>...</select>
  <select class="month" ...>...</select>
  <select class="day" ...>...</select>
</div>
...
<div id="this_other_date_container" class="date_container">
  <select class="year" ...>...</select>
  <select class="month" ...>...</select>
  <select class="day" ...>...</select>
</div>
```

Your javascript:

```
function doWhateverWithSelectDateDiv(selectDateDiv) {
  var year = selectDateDiv.find('.year'),
      month = selectDateDiv.find('.month'),
      day = selectDateDiv.find('.day');
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeBirthYear = function($obj) {
        var birthMonth = $('.birth_month', $obj);
        var birthDay = $('.birth_day', $obj);
        var birth_year = $($obj).val();
        if (birth_year != 0)
        birthMonth.attr('disabled', false);
        else {
            birthMonth.attr('disabled', true);
            birthDay.attr('disabled', true);
    }

    var changeBirthMonth = function($obj) {
        var birthMonth = $('.birth_month', $obj).val();
        var birthDay = $('.birth_day', $obj);
        var birth_year = $($obj).val();
        if (birthMonth != 0) {
            birthDay.attr('disabled', false);
            var post_url = "/index.php/admin/get_days/" + birth_year + "/" + birth_month;
            $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: post_url,
                success: function(num_of_days) {
                    birthDay.empty();
                    birthDay.append('<option value="0"> </option>');
                    for (var i = 0; i < num_of_days; i++) {
                        var string = '<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + (i + 1) + "</option>";
                        birthDay.append('<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + (i + 1) + "</option>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            birthDay.val(0);
            birthDay.attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }

    changeBirthYear($('.birth_year_1'));    
    changeBirthYear($('.birth_year_2'));    
    changeBirthMonth($('.birth_year_1'));   
    changeBirthMonth($('.birth_year_2'));   

    //somthing like that

});
```